# Merging K Sorted Arrays/Vectors Complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, merge, time-complexity

While looking into the problem of merging k sorted contiguous arrays/vectors and how it differs in implementation from merging k sorted linked lists I found two relatively easy naive solutions for merging k contiguous arrays and a nice optimized method based off of pairwise-merging that simulates how mergeSort() works. The two naive solutions I implemented seem to have the same complexity, but in a big randomized test I ran it seems one is way more inefficient than the other.

### Naive merging

My naive merging method works as follows. We create an output `vector<int>` and set it to the first of `k` vectors we are given. We then merge in the second vector, then the third, and so on. Since a typical `merge()` method that takes in two vectors and returns one is asymptotically linear in both space and time to the number of elements in both vectors the total complexity will be `O(n + 2n + 3n + ... + kn)` where `n` is the average number of elements in each list. Since we're adding `1n + 2n + 3n + ... + kn` I believe the total complexity is `O(n*k^2)`. Consider the following code:

```
vector<int> mergeInefficient(const vector<vector<int> >& multiList) {
  vector<int> finalList = multiList[0];
  for (int j = 1; j < multiList.size(); ++j) {
    finalList = mergeLists(multiList[j], finalList);
  }

  return finalList;
}
```

### Naive selection

My second naive solution works as follows:

```
/**
 * The logic behind this algorithm is fairly simple and inefficient.
 * Basically we want to start with the first values of each of the k
 * vectors, pick the smallest value and push it to our finalList vector.
 * We then need to be looking at the next value of the vector we took the
 * value from so we don't keep taking the same value. A vector of vector
 * iterators is used to hold our position in each vector. While all iterators
 * are not at the .end() of their corresponding vector, we maintain a minValue
 * variable initialized to INT_MAX, and a minValueIndex variable and iterate over
 * each of the k vector iterators and if the current iterator is not an end position
 * we check to see if it is smaller than our minValue. If it is, we update our minValue
 * and set our minValue index (this is so we later know which iterator to increment after
 * we iterate through all of them). We do a check after our iteration to see if minValue
 * still equals INT_MAX. If it has, all iterators are at the .end() position, and we have
 * exhausted every vector and can stop iterative over all k of them. Regarding the complexity
 * of this method, we are iterating over `k` vectors so long as at least one value has not been
 * accounted for. Since there are `nk` values where `n` is the average number of elements in each
 * list, the time complexity = O(nk^2) like our other naive method.
 */
vector<int> mergeInefficientV2(const vector<vector<int> >& multiList) {
  vector<int> finalList;
  vector<vector<int>::const_iterator> iterators(multiList.size());

  // Set all iterators to the beginning of their corresponding vectors in multiList
  for (int i = 0; i < multiList.size(); ++i) iterators[i] = multiList[i].begin();

  int k = 0, minValue, minValueIndex;

  while (1) {
    minValue = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterators.size(); ++i){
      if (iterators[i] == multiList[i].end()) continue;

      if (*iterators[i] < minValue) {
        minValue = *iterators[i];
        minValueIndex = i;
      }
    }

    iterators[minValueIndex]++;

    if (minValue == INT_MAX) break;
    finalList.push_back(minValue);
  }

  return finalList;
}
```

### Random simulation

Long story short, I built a simple randomized simulation that builds a multidimensional `vector<vector<int>>`. The multidimensional vector starts with `2` vectors each of size `2`, and ends up with `600` vectors each of size `600`. Each vector is sorted, and the sizes of the larger container and each child vector increase by two elements every iteration. I time how long it takes for each algorithm to perform like this:

```
clock_t clock_a_start = clock();
finalList = mergeInefficient(multiList);
clock_t clock_a_stop = clock();

clock_t clock_b_start = clock();
finalList = mergeInefficientV2(multiList);
clock_t clock_b_stop = clock();
```

I then built the following plot:

[image: plot]

My calculations say the two naive solutions (merging and selecting) both have the same time complexity but the above plot shows them as very different. At first I rationalized this by saying there may be more overhead in one vs the other, but then realized that the overhead should be a constant factor and not produce a plot like the following. What is the explanation for this? I assume my complexity analysis is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if two algorithms have the same complexity (`O(nk^2)` in your case) they may end up having enormously different running times depending upon your size of input and the 'constant' factors involved.

For example, if an algorithm runs in `n/1000` time and another algorithm runs in `1000n` time, they both have the same asymptotic complexity but they shall have very different running times for 'reasonable' choices of `n`.

Moreover, there are effects caused by caching, compiler optimizations etc that may change the running time significantly.

For your case, although your calculation of complexities seem to be correct, but in the first case, the actual running time shall be `(nk^2 + nk)/2` whereas in the second case, the running time shall be `nk^2`. Notice that the division by `2` may be significant because as `k` increases the `nk` term shall be negligible.

For a third algorithm, you can modify the Naive selection by maintaining a heap of `k` elements containing the first elements of all the `k` vectors. Then your selection process shall take `O(logk)` time and hence the complexity shall reduce to `O(nklogk)`.

Comment: Yeah I naively (no pun intended) underestimated the lower order terms that still exist as well as the multiplication of constant factors (1/2 for example). Thanks your explanation makes sense. As far as `O(nklog(k))` the three ways I've found have been 1.) sorting an array of all nk elements, 2.) pairwise merging, and 3.) using a heap as you have said.